# Changing the page in the frame control after clicking in specific buttons inside each page Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

the code in XAML :

```
<Frame x:Name="MainFrame" Content="{Binding CurrentPage,Converter={local:ApplicationPageValueConverter}}" />
```

and in the windowsBiewModel :

```
public AppilicationPage _currentPage = AppilicationPage.Main;
    public AppilicationPage CurrentPage
    {
        get {
            return _currentPage;
        }
        set {
            _currentPage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPage");
        }
    }
```

What should I do after that ?

Comment: Assign a different `CurrentPage` in the button click handler? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: No , I did that : but the page still the same

Comment: Are you bothered about what solution you use for navigation, or do you just want something that works?

Comment: something works correctly only

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments.
Here's something to consider.
A simpler container for a child view is just a contentcontrol. This works with usercontrols rather than pages. It's a lighter weight solution because there's no backwards forwards navigation journal or it's controls which are often hidden on frames.

If button A always takes you to view A then this is arguably a view responsibility and maybe viewmodels don't need to come into it at all.
From:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmPvL3r385QhgooOmyjgYmpQeM2kVw
You click a button and it has a view type associated with it:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             Button.Click="Button_Click"
              >
        <Button Content="Home" Tag="{x:Type local:HomeView}"/>
        <Button Content="Departments" Tag="{x:Type local:DepartmentView}"/>
    </ListBox>
    <ContentControl Name="NavigationParent"
                    Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

This is pretty basic stuff but retains state using a dictionary:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Navigate(typeof(HomeView));
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)e.OriginalSource;
        Navigate(btn.Tag as Type);
    }

    private void Navigate (Type viewType)
    {
        UserControl uc;
        if (Views.ContainsKey(viewType))
        {
            uc = Views[viewType];
        }
        else
        {
            uc = (UserControl)Activator.CreateInstance(viewType);
            Views[viewType] = uc;
        }
        NavigationParent.Content = uc;
    }
    private Dictionary<Type, UserControl> Views = new Dictionary<Type, UserControl>();
}
```

You could arguably improve that by binding a listbox itemssource and template a collection of objects with display name and parameterised command. Pass the type as a parameter.

Another direction would be to use a listbox similarly but instead of buttons, bind selected item and rely on which is current.
Combine that with viewmodel first templating.

Without binding the buttons that could be:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LoginViewModel}">
        <local:LoginUC/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserViewModel}">
        <local:UserUC/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Login Page"
                Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Type local:LoginViewModel}"
                />
        <Button Content="User Page"
                Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Type local:UserViewModel}"
                />
    </StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                    Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"
                    />
</Grid>
```

and the viewmodel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object currentViewModel;

    public object CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return currentViewModel; }
        set { currentViewModel = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private RelayCommand<Type> navigateCommand;
    public RelayCommand<Type> NavigateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return navigateCommand
              ?? (navigateCommand = new RelayCommand<Type>(
                vmType =>
                {
                    CurrentViewModel = null;
                    CurrentViewModel = Activator.CreateInstance(vmType);
                }));
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Note setting the bound current viewmodel to null before the viewmodel.
This guarantees you get a new instance of the view.